# unzip unable to open archive when run from a script

Tags: bash, amazon-s3, wget, unzip

When I run these commands together, the 'unzip' says:

**"unzip: cannot find or ope /tmp/SOME.zip, /tmp/SOME.zip.zip, or /tmp/SOME.zip.ZIP"**

```
wget https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/x/y/z/SOME.zip -O /tmp/SOME.zip
unzip /tmp/SOME.zip -d /opt
```

However, when I run them individually, they both work successfully on their own.

Other details:

1. The bytes/size of SOME.zip bytes is the same regardless of approach
2. When 'unzip' fails, the SOME.zip file looks like this "SOME.zip?"
3. OS -Ubuntu 14.x
4. Running script and individual commands as 'sudo'
5. No gzip or encryption on the SOME.zip file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting the commands together:

`wget https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/x/y/z/SOME.zip -O /tmp/SOME.zip && unzip /tmp/SOME.zip -d /opt`

Comment: The root cause of my problem is that the script file had a '\r' character in it and wget downloaded file and appended an extra char to the file name.  I ran dos2unix on it and resolved the whole file.  But, yes, adding them together like this helped since the \r was no longer on the file name.